# Get a permanent URL of file in OneDrive using .NET Live SDK

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, onedrive

Some files in OneDrive have an attribute called 'Source' and accroding a documentation it's a Preauthenticated URL and they expire and should not be stored or reused later.
So my question is using Live SDK for .NET how can I get a permanent URL of the file (ex. jpg image) I uploaded and use this link all the time I want?

NOTE: this URL must not be dependent from my Live account and I usually use these links in BitmapImage and provide them for other users.

Thanks

Comment: If you check out [this section of the OneDrive api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh826531.aspx#file_links), you can get share links that are permanent. Users must still authenticate and use an access token.

Answer (score 0):

The LiveSDKs do not support getting a permanent link on an item within OneDrive that can be accessed outside of the LiveSDK's authentication system.

To get a link within the LiveSDK you can download a file from OneDrive with a request like this:

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!126/content?suppress_redirects=true?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

To see more information about interaction with files consult:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx

Comment: I put the note that I share this link among other users so no access token should be presented here

Comment: Updated with: The LiveSDKs do not support getting a permanent link on an item within OneDrive that can be accessed outside of the LiveSDK's authentication system.